# What does PipeMapRed do in Hadoop streaming?

Tags: hadoop-streaming

I run a hadoop job for more than one time, and every time it takes too much time to finish, like **15 mins **　in all.

I checked the `syslog`, found out that, `org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed` was doing something for about **10 mins**, and after `PipeMapRed` is done, `MapTask` took over and finished in less than **1 min**, what the heck?

What does `PipeMapRed` do actually? Why is it so time-consuming?

Here is some log printed by `PipeMapRed`:

```
17:00:57,307 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=1633/1
17:00:59,782 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=10000/8763/0 in:5000=10000/2 [rec/s] out:4381=8763/2 [rec/s]
17:01:07,310 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=60670/59051
17:01:12,610 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=100000/97904/0 in:6666=100000/15 [rec/s] out:6526=97904/15 [rec/s]
17:01:17,332 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=126104/124334
17:01:27,378 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=181681/179714
17:01:30,514 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=200000/198233/0 in:6060=200000/33 [rec/s] out:6007=198233/33 [rec/s]
17:01:37,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=244642/242654
```

Answer (score 3):

The logs you provided are logs from mapreduce streaming, you can see how many records are being read and write, for example:

```
R/W/S=10000/8763/0 in:5000=10000/2 [rec/s] out:4381=8763/2 [rec/s]
```

First part stands for how many records are:

```
READ/WRITE/SKIPPED=10000/8763/0
```

Second part is about how fast do you process records, so you read 5000 records/sec and write 4381 records/sec

15 min per (streaming) mapreduce job is totally ok, if not to little :)